# Complex cobordism and Chern numbers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $L$ be the Lazard's universal ring, and $R=\mathbb{Z}[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n,\cdots]$, regarded as a graded ring with the degree of $b_i$ equal to $2i$. Let $\theta: L\rightarrow R$ be the homomorphism carrying the universal formal group law $\mu^L$ to the formal group law
$$\mu^R(x_1,x_2)=\exp(\log(x_1)+\log(x_2)),$$
where the power series 
$$\exp(x)=x+\sum_{i\geq 1}b_ix^{i+1},$$
and $\log(x)$ its inverse, denoted as
$$\log(x)=x+\sum_{i\geq 1}m_ix^{i+1}.$$
Let $MU$ be the complex cobordism spectrum, and by Quillen's theorem we have the following commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
L @>\theta>> R\\
@V \cong V V @VV \cong V\\
\pi_*(MU) @>>h> H_*(MU;\mathbb{Z})
\end{CD}

where $h$ is the Hurewicz homomorphism.

In Section 9, Part II of

*Adams, J. F.*, Stable homotopy and generalised homology, Chicago Lectures in Mathematics. Chicago - London: The University of Chicago Press. X, 373 p.  3.00 (1974). [ZBL0309.55016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0309.55016).**

it is stated that the class $[\mathbb{C} P^n]\in\pi_*(MU)$ is sent to $(n+1)m_n\in H_*(MU;\mathbb{Z})$ by $h$, and it is indicated there that the argument is a Chern number computation, but I am not seeing the argument.**

I would greatly appreciate your help if you could sketch the proof or point out a reference containing a proof. Thank you!

Comment: I think the idea to make this a characteristic class computation is that the image of $[\mathbb{C}P^n]$ under the Hurewicz homomorphism is the same as pushing forward the fundamental class into $BU$ via classifying the tangent bundle, then using the Thom isomorphism to get a homology class in $MU$.

Comment: @Connor Malin Thank you for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a key result that the composite
$$ MU_* \xrightarrow{h} H_*(MU;\mathbb Z) \xrightarrow[\sim]{\Phi^{\vee}}H_*(BU;\mathbb Z),$$

where $\Phi^{\vee}$ is the dual of the Thom isomorphism $\Phi$, agrees with evaluating on normal Chern numbers.

In other words, $\langle \Phi(c), h([M])\rangle = \bar c(M)$ for all $c \in H^*(BU)$ and for all $[M] \in MU_*$.

(A reference in the real case is the diagram on page 228 of *A concise course in algebraic topology* by J.P.May. The complex case is identical.)

So the assertion is just a Chern number calculation:

$h([\mathbb CP^n]) = (n+1)m_n$ if and only if, for all $c \in H^{2n}(BU;\mathbb Z)$, $$\langle \Phi(c), (n+1)m_n\rangle = \bar c(\mathbb CP^n).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference! They are very helpful.

Comment: In the first displayed line, should it be $\pi_*(MU)$ instead of $MU_*$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The latter is standard notation for the former.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.